# How to update a subscription to a GET-request after posting new data to the backend

Tags: angular

I have implemented a service which utilizes Angular's HttpClient to make a GET-request to my backend. It returns a list of employees:

```
  getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.EMPLOYEES_URL);
  }
```

I subscribe to this service inside the `ngOnInit()` method of a table-component, filling an array with the returned data. The rows of my table are built dynamically from the content inside the array.

Now, I am posting a new employee to my backend. The table, however, is not updated.

My understanding of Angular observables is that they watch the backend (in this case) and whenever something changes, the code inside the subscription is executed. Apparently this understanding is wrong and I wonder: How can I force an update of the subscription inside my table-component?

Comment: They absolutely do not "watch the backend" unless you have something (e.g. websockets or polling) doing that. You've made a single request; you want the updated employees you'll need to make the request again. Here's one pattern I've found useful: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: I am posting a new employee from within a different component though. After posting this employee, I would have to make the GET request inside the table component, which I don't know how to. I was hoping that there is a way to force an update of all subscriptions to thie GET-request.

Comment: The observable you return from the method only emits once, when the response is received, then completes. If you want a way to emit data to subscribers multiple times, you'll need to manage an observable yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the peice of information you may be missing is that the Observables returned from HttpClient methods complete after the first return.

As you are using 2 separate components you will need some means of informing that new data must be fetched, or some way of keeping the observable open - we can do this with a service. I think the following should work for you.

In the service we could define:

```
private employeesUpdated$ = new Subject<void>();

employees$ = employeesUpdated$.pipe(
  startsWith({}),
  switchMap(() => 
    this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.EMPLOYEES_URL)
  )
);
```

You could then, on your POST add:

```
this.httpClient.post<something>(... stuff ...).pipe(
  tap(() => {
    this.employeesUpdated.next();
  })
)
```

This will allow you to subscribe to employees$ in your component, and each time you post a new one, it will perform a new get request, as the observable will stay open. Do dispose of this subscription properly though!

You can find lots more information about rxjs and Observables from the official docs here:
https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview
This is also a good resource:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/

---

If you wanted to just append to the initially got array, rather than getting everything from the server after each creation, I think something like this would work:

In the service:

```
private employeeAdded$ = new Subject<Employee>();
private serverEmployees$ = this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.EMPLOYEES_URL);

employees$ = merge(
  serverEmployees$,
  employeeAdded$.pipe(
    map(x => ([x]))
  )
).pipe(
  scan((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [])
);
```

Basically merge will take multiple observables, and output a single one. This goes into scan which will accumulate using a provided function, emitting after each accumulation. Docs for these are
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge and
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/scan.

For your create (bear in mind for this, parrot the object back from the server on post, so it has an id for the entity):

```
this.httpClient.post<something>(... stuff ...).pipe(
  tap((employee: Employee) => {
    this.employeesUpdated.next(employee);
  })
)
```

Comment: What @plabbee mention make sense and if you want to avoid the backend call when you post new employee after the success of post instead of triggering the backend call to fetch the employees again you can append this new employee in the existing array of employees.

Comment: Completely agree @Darpan, and is very much the more efficient approach - is just slightly more complex to implement.

Comment: @Plabbee: This is such a great answer, thx very much! I tried it out and it works beautifully. I would like to ask 2 follow up questions tho: 
1. In order to send the POST request, I have to subscribe to the 2. method you have shown. I wonder: If I do something inside this subscription, will this be executed before the pipe-operation has been executed or after? 
2. You've mentioned it would be more efficient not to execute a GET request after posting a new client, but instead append the client to the existing array. Could you - unless ofc it is too complex - sketch out how this can be done?

Comment: Subscriptions to the Observable are pushed to after the pipe, so what is in the pipe will be executed first. Yeah, sure I can. I'll update my answer with it as an alternative at the end - may be tomorrow or the day after unless someone else jumps in with it.

Comment: that would be awesome, thx Plabbee! 
The reason why I asked the 1. question is: I want to emit an event inside the subscription. This event seems to reach my table-component before the table rows are updated. I assume that's because after posting a new employee the GET employees method is executed, but it takes some time to actually get all employees. Right after sending the GET request the event inside my subscription seems to be fired and reaches its target before GET employees has finished. I just assume this. I can add a setTimeOut inside my subscription, but this is not a nice solution.

Comment: nevermind tho, this problem shouldn't occur if I just append entries to my array anyways.

Comment: Have added a way to append. A few different operators used that you may have not come across before - have added the docs for them. Hope it works out for you!

If all good - mark the answer as accepted for me :)

Comment: thx so much, Plabbee! This works beautifully and you have helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem - good luck!