# Angular - add and remove entries from an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

Consider a table component, which holds the variable `rows = Employees[]`. The rows are set by a service, which I am currently trying to implement. The challenge that I am facing is that I want to be able to both add and remove rows to my table without reloading all my data afterwards.

I have asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251269/how-to-update-a-subscription-to-a-get-request-after-posting-new-data-to-the-back/72251514#72251514) before and received some amazing help, which has led me to the following intermediate solution:

```
private employeeAdded$ = new Subject<Employee>();
private serverEmployees$ = this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.EMPLOYEES_URL);

employees$ = merge(
    serverEmployees$,
    employeeAdded$.pipe(
        map(x => [x])
      )
    ).pipe(
      scan((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [])
    );
```

Just to be clear: This code allows for initializing the `employees$` observable with an `Employee[]` array and also adding another employee to it without having to send another GET request to my server to retrieve all employees sitting there. I want to avoid sending a GET request to my server every time I add or remove an employee.

The problem, however, is: I don't know how to remove an employee from `employees$`.

I was thinking: I will probably have to add another observable `employeeDeleted$ = new Subject<number>()` and somehow integrate this within the `merge` call. Currently, my backend simply returns the id of the deleted employee upon sending a DELETE request. If I was to return the entire list of employees without the deleted one instead, I could integrate this into my `merge` call. This, however, is exactly what I am trying to avoid: Having to reload the entire database every time I delete an employee.

Anyways: I don't have a solution for this problem. I am interested if this can be done in a similar fashion as adding an employee, or if it requires substantially more effort, in which case I might go with sending another GET-request.

Comment: you have the data at your disposal right, so you can use it to add or delete. One possible solution can be to implement this using NGRX, where a store can be created to store your employee list, and then you can have actions to add/update/delete from the store. This would be a substantial effort work wise, but its benefits outweight

Comment: @mak15: This sounds very interesting, I've never really come across NGRX stores before. I wonder though: Would I be able to achieve sth similar using session storage? I don't really have an idea as on how to integrate this nicely into my application, but I am thinking: I am trying to avoid multiple database calls. Isn't this what the session storage is there for?